# Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active

Tags: php, class, object, scope

I am trying to use a PHP function from within a public static function like so (I've shortened things a bit):

```
class MyClass {

public static function first_function() {

    function inside_this() {    
            $some_var = self::second_function(); // doesnt work inside this function
    }               

    // other code here...

} // End first_function

protected static function second_function() { 

    // do stuff

} // End second_function

} // End class PayPalDimesale
```

That's when I get the error "Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active".

If I call `second_function` outside of the `inside_this` function, it works fine:

```
class MyClass {

public static function first_function() {

    function inside_this() {    
            // some stuff here  
    }               

    $some_var = self::second_function(); // this works

} // End first_function

protected static function second_function() { 

    // do stuff

} // End second_function

} // End class PayPalDimesale
```

What do I need to do to be able to use `second_function` from within the `inside_this` function?

Comment: Did you try a closure? `function inside_this() use($self) {`

Comment: I realized too late that `self` is not a variable...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because **All functions  in PHP have the global scope** - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

So you have to do:

```
 function inside_this() {    
   $some_var = MyClass::second_function(); 
 }
```

Comment: @JohnRobinson That is because that method is protected.

Comment: @xdazz, is there anyway to save *MyClass* into a variable and pass it to the function instead of hard coding the class name `MyClass` into the code? (otherwise if we change the name of the class, we need to search and replace "MyClass" throughout the file)

Answer (score 3):

Works with PHP 5.4:

```
<?php
class A
{
  public static function f()
  {
    $inner = function()
    {
      self::g();
    };

    $inner();
  }

  private static function g()
  {
    echo "g\n";
  }
}

A::f();
```

Output:

```
g
```

Comment: His is `protected`, not `private`.

Comment: @Cole Johnson, private is *more* restrictive, which is why I used it in my example.

Comment: @Matthew Is there any documentation on why is this not working in 5.3 version of php , and it is working in 5.4 version

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara, I'm not sure if it's mentioned explicitly, but here you'll see that PHP 5.4 introduced `$this` in closures: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php. Not the same thing, but it's related.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to do exactly this but it doesn't work (PHP 5.35 & PHP 5.4), I get the "Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active". Any idea ?

Comment: yeah you are totally right, I didn't updgrated correctly, thank you, it works better now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first function to

```
public static function first_function() {

    $function = function() {    
            $some_var = self::second_function(); //  now will work
    };               
    ///To call the function do this
    $function();
    // other code here...

} // End first_function
```